# Подключение JS файлов в HTML Документ

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Только начинаю верстать, прошу помощи. Есть несколько скриптов на странице (кнопка наверх, плавная прокрутка по пунктам меню, и адаптивное меню с фиксацией). Решил их вынести все во внешний файл, т.к все 4 скрипта в теге head заняли много места. В связи с чем наверное глупый, но важный для меня вопрос. Я могу подключить всего 1 js файл, где будут друг за другом прописаны сразу все 4 скрипта, или мне нужно для каждого скрипта создавать отдельный файл, и подключать 4 файла?

Comment: можно друг за другом сколькоугодно файлов, а можно 1н файл с кучей кода, вам решать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я лично делаю следующим образом:

В процессе разработки у меня есть много скриптов в разных файлах, так, что каждый из них можно безболезненно исключить из сборки и это не будет особой задачей. А сборщик уже упаковывает все скрипты в 2 файла: `vendor.js` (для библиотек, плагинов) и `app.js` для скриптов фронта. Если у меня есть скрипты, которые не влияют на верстку в целом, но используются на одной-двух страницах, подключаю их отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать вот такую конструкцию в вашем файле, для загрузки остальных файлов:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://myScript.js'; //любой, Вашей душе, угодный путь до скрипта
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все в одном или каждый по отдельности в `head`-е страницы:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
```

Можно как объединить так и по отдельности подключать. Если Вы ещё на этапе разработки то рекомендую Вам не объединять их пока что, так как проще дедажить код. А в продакшин собрать все в один и подключить.